# Insert elements/values into specific child element of XML column in t-sql

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008, I would like to insert some elements and values into a specific child element of an xml column based on the value of another of that element's children (ID in this case). The xml currently looks like this:

```
<Profile>
  <ID>16</ID>
  <User>
    <ID>BC4A18CA-AFB5-4268-BDA9-C990DAFE7783</ID>
    <Name>test</Name>
    <Activities />
  </User>
</Profile>
```

However, there could potentially be multiple `<User>` elements within the xml, and I need to insert only into the `<User>` of a specific `<ID>` value. How can I achieve this in MS SQL Server 2008/ t-sql?

**Edit:**
To simplify, I am grabbing the xml from that column and setting it to a variable:

```
DECLARE @profiles_xml xml
DECLARE @profile_id int
SET @profile_id = 16
SET @profiles_xml = (SELECT profiles from tbl_applied_profiles WHERE
profiles.value('(Profile/ID)[1]','int')= @profile_id)
```

The resulting xml value of @profiles_xml looks like what I have above.

Comment: Mikael Eriksson posted an answer that addresses this question on a similar question I asked, the answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234175/use-of-xml-modify-to-insert-parameters-into-specific-element-of-an-xml-column