# SQL Server - how to insert a substring?

Tags: sql-server

I have a string like

```
`...<..../><... id='someID' .../><...../>....`
```

(the total length of that string is more than 15k chars, it's an XML form definition)

Inside of that string I have the `someID` value. I want to put after the element containing that value a new string:

```
...<..../><... id='someID' .../><my_new_string><...../>....
```

I tried to split that long string basing on the `someID` value, but that approach is too slow. How can I achieve that on the other way ?

Or maybe is it possible to select the substring `<... id='someID' .../>` ?

Answer (score 1):

SQL server can work with XML. You do not need to use substring.
A simular problem was solved on this page: [xml.modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234175/use-of-xml-modify-to-insert-parameters-into-specific-element-of-an-xml-column)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Replace? For example:

```
REPLACE(yourString, yourPattern, yourPattern + newString);
```

Using your example, it would look something like:

```
REPLACE('...<..../><... id='someID' .../><...../>....',
        '<... id=''someID'' .../>',
        '<... id=''someID'' .../><my_new_string>');
```

Please notice I escaped the ' characters around "someID".

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what data type your string is: `xml` or `(n)varchar`? For `xml`, you can use the various [data type methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx); for `(n)varchar` the [`STUFF()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) inserts one string into another string.