# Combine and modify XML in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005, is it possible to combine XML and add an attribute at same time?

*Unfortunately, due to project restrictions, I need a SQL Server 2005 solution.*

Consider the following, where I need to combine XML from multiple rows within a new `<root>` element...

```
; WITH [TestTable] AS (
    SELECT 7 AS [PkId], CAST('<data><id>11</id><id>12</id></data>' AS XML) AS [Data]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, CAST('<data><id>22</id></data>' AS XML)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 43, CAST('<data><id>33</id></data>' AS XML)
)
SELECT (
    SELECT XMLDATA as [*]
    FROM (
        SELECT [Data] AS [*]
        FROM [TestTable]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) AS DATA(XMLDATA)
    FOR XML PATH('root')
)
```

This produces the desired output of...

```
<root>
  <data><id>11</id><id>12</id></data>
  <data><id>22</id></data>
  <data><id>33</id></data>
</root>
```

But what I need to do, if possible, is add an attribute to the *existing* data element in each of the rows with the `PkId` value.  The desired output would then look like this...

```
<root>
  <data pkid="7"><id>11</id><id>12</id></data>
  <data pkid="12"><id>22</id></data>
  <data pkid="43"><id>33</id></data>
</root>
```

My gut feeling is that this is going to be impossible without the use of a cursor, but if anybody knows a way of doing it I'd love to hear it.

---

At the request of @MattA, here is an example of some random data in the table...

```
[PkId]  [UserId]  [SubmittedDate]      [Data]
1       1         2015-03-24 12:34:56  '<data><id>1</id><id>2</id></data>'
2       1         2015-03-23 09:15:52  '<data><id>3</id></data>'
3       2         2015-03-22 16:01:23  '<data><id>4</id><id>5</id></data>'
4       1         2015-03-21 13:45:34  '<data><id>6</id></data>'
```

Please note, that to make the question easier, I stated that I needed the `PkId` column as the attribute to the data.  This is not actually the case - instead I need the `[SubmittedDate]` column to be used.  I apologise if this caused confusion.

Using `UserId=1` as a filter, the XML I would like from the above would be...

```
<root>
  <data submitteddate="2015-03-24T12:34:56"><id>1</id><id>2</id></data>
  <data submitteddate="2015-03-23T09:15:52"><id>3</id></data>
  <data submitteddate="2015-03-21T13:45:34"><id>6</id></data>
</root>
```

The date would be formatted using the 126 date format available from [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: XML is fully CRUD compliant in SQL Server.  I'll work up an example in my free time today unless someone else gets to it first.

Comment: See if this helps you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234175/use-of-xml-modify-to-insert-parameters-into-specific-element-of-an-xml-column

Answer (score 2):

Here's the quick answer for you.  XML does support "modify", but shredding on a small data set like this works quite well too.

**Code**

```
--The existing XML
DECLARE @XML XML = '<root>
  <data><id>11</id></data>
  <data><id>22</id></data>
  <data><id>33</id></data>
</root>'

--XML Shredded Back to a table
;WITH
ShreddedXML AS (
    SELECT
        ID = FieldAlias.value('(id)[1]','int')
    FROM
        @XML.nodes('/root/data') AS TableAlias(FieldAlias)
), ArbitraryPKGenerator AS (
    SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS PKid,
            ID
    FROM    ShreddedXML
)
SELECT  A.PKId AS "@PKid",
        A.ID AS "id"
FROM    ArbitraryPKGenerator AS A
FOR     XML PATH('data'), ROOT('root')
```

**And the XML**

```
<root>
  <data PKid="2015-03-24T09:44:55.770">
    <id>11</id>
  </data>
  <data PKid="2015-03-24T09:44:55.770">
    <id>22</id>
  </data>
  <data PKid="2015-03-24T09:44:55.770">
    <id>33</id>
  </data>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt... the `pkid` was a simple example, but not actually what I need. The actual data that will be added as an attribute will be from a `datetime` column in the table... so I'm not sure this method is going to work for my specific case

Comment: Have a look at the update.  I put CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to showcase a datetime being the @PKid column's source.  What you'll be doing in that step is joining to your source data and pulling the column you want from the source table.  I think CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is 2005 compatible, but GET_DATE() will work too.

Comment: Getting closer Matt - and I really do appreciate your effort, but the value for the attribute is taken from a **column** in the table that also contains the XML fields.  So I need the `<data>` for the XML in the row to have an attribute of `pkid` where the value of that attribute is the datetime value from the same row.

Comment: Please add a sample of the table where you expect to get your datetime column from.  Please also include the value as it correlates to the id field.  I can whip up a quick example but I'd rather just nail exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: See updated question - I hope that makes it clearer, and I apologise for any confusion.  I was trying to make the question easier by just stating the `pkid` field, with the intention of changing to the `submitteddate` field after it was working

Comment: No problem.  Give me about 5 min.  We're going to go a different direction since these are all in the same table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73683/discussion-between-matt-a-and-freefaller).

Comment: Really sorry Matt, I've reached the end of my working day, and I need to leave the office!  Thanks for you help though